# Ansible - How to detect that you are on a Linux machine with a GUI system installed?

Tags: user-interface, ansible

I am trying to setup my dotfiles/machine bootstrap stuff with ansible, and I want to install a bunch of GUI tools, but only if I am on a machine that supports it. I am using `ansible_os_family == 'Debian'` to detect that apt-get would work. Not sure how to check if, for e.g gtk or something like that is installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ansible has a lot of [support for package managers](http://docs.ansible.com/list_of_packaging_modules.html), and will happily work well with [apt](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_module.html). Unfortunately, there isn't currently a way to check if a package is installed using this module. However, this can be done by registering the result of a command. Something like this should work:

```
- name: Check if gtk is installed
  command: dpkg-query -l gtk
  register: gtk_check

- name: Install GTK application 
  apt: name=gtk-program state=present
  when: gtk_check.stdout.find('no packages found') != -1
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at the facts that are reported by running Ansible on this service to see if there's a specific fact you can check.  From the [Ansible FAQ](http://docs.ansible.com/faq.html) just run this to see all the facts:

```
ansible -m setup hostname
```

If that doesn't provide anything useful then the next option is to run a task and save the results to a variable that you can test for.  The task could be invoking a command, checking if a package is installed, etc.

A while ago I had to write a playbook that might end up getting run on either a redhat or debian system, so I needed to check if yum was installed, and based on that ensure that either python-apt was installed or a number of other redhat packages.  Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
- name: Check if yum exists
  stat: path=/usr/bin/yum
  register: yum

# The python-apt package must be installed before the apt module below
# can be invoked...
- name: Check if python-apt is installed
  shell: dpkg -l python-apt | grep python-apt
  register: apt_status
  when: yum.stat.exists == False

- name: Install python-apt
  command: apt-get install -y python-apt
  when: yum.stat.exists == False and apt_status.stdout.find('un') == 0

# procmail & postfix are needed for the lockfile command & ability to
# send e-mail
- name: Install required packages
  yum: pkg={{ item }} state=present
  with_items:
    - procmail
    - postfix
  when: yum.stat.exists == True
```

The first task just checks if /usr/bin/yum exists and stores the results in a variable named "yum".  The second tasks will check to see if python-apt is installed only if yum doesn't exist (so it's assuming that the lack of yum indicates this is actually a debian system).  The third task forces python-apt to be installed only if it doesn't exist (and it's a debian system).  The last task will install a few packages via yum only if yum does exist.

It's a little bit long-winded, but using one or two of these above methods should help you figure out the best way to determine if a GUI is installed.  You may be able to invoke /sbin/runlevel via the shell or command module (runlevel 5 typically means X11 is running), or you could invoke dpkg as I did above to test if a specific package is installed.  Or you could simply use the stat module to see if a path or file like /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc exists.  Then it's just a matter of registering the results of the task to a variable and using an appropriate "when" clause in subsequent tasks.